# Is it possible to compile a string of Clojure code to classes from java?

Tags: java, clojure, compilation

I need to compile some clojure file into java bytecode files, store them on the disk, so I would be able to load/execute them later.

I tried the following:

```
RT.load("clojure/core");
RT.init();
String clazz = "(ns org.rogach.avalanche.build (:gen-class)) (defn -doStuff [] (println 1))";
Compiler.load(new StringReader(clazz));
Compiler.load(new StringReader("(compile 'org.rogach.avalanche.build)"));
```

But it fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not locate org/rogach/avalanche/build__init.class or org/rogach/avalanche/build.clj on classpath
```

To be fair, exactly the same thing happens if I execute that code from clojure REPL directly.

Also, this approach doesn't let me to specify output directory for class files, which also important.

How can I compile that clojure code to classfiles?

Comment: Curious: why do you need to compile the Clojure code into class files? AOT compilation adds a lot of complications, normally it is easier to  just compile/load Clojure code from .clj files at runtime. Sounds a bit like an "XY problem" to me...

Comment: @mikera - I have a program, that takes clojure file as a config file. I already know how to eval that code, but that requires initializing the clojure runtime, and that takes ~1 second - I hoped to work around that by compiling the config only when it is changed, and if it is not changed, simply load and execute pre-compiled class files.

Comment: Then an answer to this question won't help you.... loading and initialising `clojure.core` is almost certainly what causes the startup time, not loading and compiling your config file.

Comment: So there's absoultely no way to execute clojure code without ~1 second overhead? There are no ways to speed it up?

Comment: Clojure will always have a longish startup time until someone revamps the compiler / bootstrapping code. My recommended solution right now (if you care about latency) is to keep a persistent JVM / REPL instance running so that startup time isn't a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect the answer is: not directly.

The unit of AOT compilation is the namespace, and the compile function seems to look for a namespace in a file.
I think it is necessarily to write the Clojure files to the correct relative path so the compile function can find the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Is there no way to hack deep into compiler API to compile? I don't mind duplicating some code from clojure compiler, I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Programmatically compiling java code using clojure](http://nakkaya.com/2010/09/20/programmatically-compiling-java-code-using-clojure/) by Nakkaya.  I've used it in the past, and was the one who made the comment on how to extend it to interfaces.  I'm not sure about your use-case, but this does what you asked.